# Numbers with comma as decimal separator in Databricks

Tags: database, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-science, databricks

Hi I am trying to read a csv file where the floating numbers have comma as decimal separator. When I read the file with Spark, it will just ignore the comma sign and concatenate everything together and I end up with something like:

77563215,23 becomes 7756321523.00.

How can I make sure that while reading it through spark, I get the same number as my original csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please read CSV file using option("locale", "de-DE")

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: this is a comment for the question not an answer

Comment: It looks like an answer to me, but I'm hesitant to vote one way or the other.